# fusion chart legend

Tags: legend, fusioncharts

I am using FCF_Pie3D.swf to display a chart.I set showLegend="1", but it does not show a legend/label. Why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FusionCharts Free Pie charts does not support legends. It is supported on FusionCharts v3.2 and above.

Comment: First example on a demo page states differently. In the top right corner there is a pie chart with a legend. False advertising?

Comment: The legend there is generated using HTML and is not part of the flash component. :) Check out the source code of that page!